# Brake fluid squirts out of brake lever

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, brake-levers

We noticed tonight that one of the brake levers, whenever you actuated it and let go rapidly, brake fluid would squirt out (black and oily substance).

I'm wondering if there would be some things that I could look for at home before bringing it in the shop. Maybe, an easy thing to look for? I would hate for it to be just a small screw to tighten or something.

Gear list:

- Brake Levers Tektro Auriga
- Brakes   Tektro Auriga, Hydraulic disc, 160mm

Comment: If it's black, then you're far beyond needing a fluid flush anyway.

Comment: Where does it come out? Being black suggests to me that it might just be some old over flow that was trapped somewhere.

Comment: That said, it's unlikely to be just a small screw, so a trip to the shops might be in order, if you're not comfortable with hydraulic brakes why risk it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were coming out around the bleed screw, then checking the tightness of the screw and/or the condition of the o-ring it's hiding would be in order. Taking the screw out to look at the o-ring is something you should only do if you're prepared to bleed the brake, but it sounds like that's probably in order anyway. Bleed port o-rings getting out of place or mushed is a thing that happens.
[image]

You can also check the hose connection. Pull back the rubber shield around the hose and make sure the compression fitting is snugged in nice and securely. That coming loose would be kind of scary/weird so if it did happen you would definitely want to make sure all the threads, the olive, and the hose end and barb all looked good.

If it's anything else you probably need a new lever or complete brake. Aurigas are decent brakes but replacement seals and other rebuild type parts for them are unobtanium.

Comment: Brought to shop, they said they couldn't fix and needed to get a new part.